# Python project doesn't pick up dependencies according to the sys.path order

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, dependencies

I am using pip and python 2.7 to upgrade a dependency in my project. The global python has a lower version of the dependency, and I am running pip install with the --user option to avoid messing with the global sdks.

I am running the command `pip install --user -r requirements.txt` in the directory `workspace/myproject`. This directory is also my `PYTHONUSERBASE`
The project fails to use the upgraded version and exits. 
Here's the result of `python -m site` command

```
sys.path = [
'workspace/myproject',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1- 
py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python27.zip',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'workspace/myproject/_pip/lib/python2.7/site- 
 packages',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: 'workspace/myproject/_pip' (exists)
USER_SITE: 'workspace/myproject/_pip/lib/python2.7/site-packages' 
(exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

`pip -V` command:`pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)`

As you can see, my user site comes above the global site-package location. When I navigate to the user-site directory, I can see all the classes and modules of the latest version. The command pip list --user also shows me the version I want. Still, when I run the project, the older dependency is picked up, from the global site packages location. I used the `__file__` variable to be certain of the complete path of the imported module, and it showed

```
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'
```

However, when I run pip install with the --ignore-installed option, everything runs as expected. The sys.path has the same output but the `__file__` variable now displays the path to the user_site directory. I'll admit that I am new to python and pip, but as per the my understanding of the documentation around sys.path, python imports, and the user_site, this is not the expected behavior. Has anyone faced anything similar? Do I have the wrong understanding of how pip works with the --user option? Any inputs on this will help.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you not using a `virtualenv`?

Comment: Hey Waqas, this setup is on a legacy CI tool, and I am trying to test the version upgrade there. All the new machines use the `virtualenv`, and it's working fine with it.

Comment: Can you restart your environment and check? Caches might create problems.

Comment: You're right regarding the cache, but unfortunately, I can't restart right now. Moreover the project runs just fine when I use --ignore-installed option.